# Sound problems in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sound-card, digital-audio

I hope I reached the correct forum for this question.

I have a media computer with a third party audio card (Soundblaster audigy SE)
I use a coaxial digital audio cable connected to a Onkyo TX SR508.

if I use normal audio, the sound seems very low, I have to set volume atleast to 62 in my amplifier to hear anything, however if I set digital SPDIF I have no means of controlling the audio volume from the PC (only from the amplifier) and this can be nasty if I toggle between movies that uses Digital AC3/THX  and movies wihtouth, if I look at movies capable of AC3  the volume gets VERY loud if amp is set to 62, 32 is more than enough volume when using passthrough.

so this bothers me is how can I get the same amount of volume with or without digital output?

I tried also other soundcards, internal red light Digital audio cable...

if I connect to my television I get ok sound on any sound source via HDMI...

help :)

Comment: not sure what your exact problem is - wouldn't you always control the volume from your Onyko? Are you saying that the volume is low set to normal but on digital its too loud ? I guess it would help if I knew the problem you are trying to solve - what is the use case and what is your desired result -

Comment: all volume in the computer is set to max, and I am using digital audio driver, there is a difference between SPDIF Passthorugh and normal WDM here, when using passthrough the sound is too loud.. and in video players I cannot control volum inernally in application when using passthorugh with the good volume, I am concerned about the loudess because if I forget to set the volume down whne looking at a normal movie, I am concerned that the speakrs will go bad, or even the amp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obviously the "digital audio device" in soundpanel is not supposed to be used... using normal speaker seem to work if it is set to digital output only...

weird but works.